# Printing a number in assembly NASM using printf

Tags: assembly, printf, nasm, x86-64, calling-convention

I've been trying to get this to print 12345 for a while now. Can anyone provide a hint as to what I should do? It will print the three lines of text, then on the fourth line prints "age", which I'm guessing is a remnant in the stack from line 2.

```
    bits 64
    global main
    extern printf

    section .text
main:
    ; function setup
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32
    ;
    lea     rdi, [rel message]
    mov     al, 0
    call    printf
;above code correctly prints message

;where the issue lies
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
;sub rsp, 32

mov rax, 12345
;push rax   
mov al,0
call printf


    ; function return
    mov     eax, 0
    add     rsp, 32
    pop     rbp
    ret

    section .data
message: db      'Lab 3 - Modified Hello program',0x0D,0x0a,'COSC2425 - Pentium assembly language',0x0D,0x0a,'Processed with NASM and GNU gcc',0x0D,0x0a
count   dq  12345
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you don't even know how `printf` works which makes it hard to invoke it from assembly.

To print a number, `printf` expects two arguments, a format string and the number to print of course. Example: `printf("%d\n", 12345)`.

Now to turn that into assembly, you obviously need to declare that format string, and then pass both arguments using the appropriate convention.

Since you seem to be using sysv abi, this means the first two arguments go into `rdi` and `rsi`, respectively. You already seem to know you have to zero `al` to indicate no SSE registers used. As such, the relevant part could look like:

```
lea rdi, [rel fmt] ; address of label
mov rsi, 12345     ; or mov rsi, [count]
xor eax, eax       ; AL=0
call printf
...

section .rodata
fmt: db "%d", 0x0a, 0    ; char fmt[] = "%d\n";
```

Comment: This class is going to be the death of me. In the assignment it says to load rax with 12345.  Emailed asking for help and he says that's wrong. I've been trying to figure this one out for days.    It prints 9012345 now. Any ideas why? It has something to do with how I'm sending the string to printf

Comment: How does your code look? What I showed in my answer, works fine. You must pass the number in `rsi` to `printf`, no way around that. If you insist, you can do `mov rax, 12345; mov rsi, rax` but that's of course silly.

Comment: My code is as above, but with your version of the print 12345. It has something to do with the print message part. I had to increment 12345 by 2 and move it back into the rsi register (he said rax in the assignment) and used the exact same bit of code to print the new number. printed without the 90. It's definitely something with the string part before printing the number. I'm gonna try to figure it out! thanks!

Comment: Oh damn, should have added that, sorry! Good catch! Need to add that to end of all strings, including the format (updated the answer). Some assemblers have special directives that automatically do that.